# How to make render the elements only when they are ready in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I send a request to api and render the result as a list, some images are showing late and text are rendered first. Is there any way to prevent this?
I want to show the list only when images, classes, text are totally finished computing by logic. If they are not ready, I want to still hide them. **v-cloak** is not working!.

This is the part I'm getting trouble.

[image]

You can see, also the entire list is rendered, there are some images left.

Here is my code example.

```
    <div id="app">
    <h2>Todos:</h2>
    <ol>
        <li v-for="todo in todos">
            <!-- thre may be some more logics -->
            <img :src="todo.img" width="100px">
            {{todo.name}}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        todos: []
    },
    created: function(){
        this.requestApi();
    },
    methods: {
        requestApi(){
        this.todos = [
                { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "AAA" },
                { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "BBB" },
                { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "CCC" },
                { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "DDD" }
            ];
        }
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vxy4gnj8/3/

It's not showing clearly my problem in above jsfiddle because it's not sending to a real api and rendered too fast.

Comment: Can you show us `requestApi()`?

Comment: Sorry bro. This is my company's project and I cant show you real api. I've showed you an example bro. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-if` to only show component when `requestApi` finished:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="!isLoading">
    <h2>Todos:</h2>
    <ol>
        <li v-for="todo in todos">
            <!-- thre may be some more logics -->
            <img :src="todo.img" width="100px">
            {{todo.name}}
        </li>
    </ol>
  </div>

</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      todos: [],
      isLoading: true
  },
  created: function(){
      this.requestApi();
  },
  methods: {
      requestApi(){
        this.todos = [
          { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "AAA" },
          { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "BBB" },
          { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "CCC" },
          { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "DDD" }
        ];
        this.isLoading = false
      }
  }
})
```

Note that `isLoading` is used as a flag to check if request finishes or not.

Comment: It's not working yet bro. Some low resolution images rendered first, high resolution images rendered later.

Comment: would that necessarily wait for the images to complete loading?

Comment: I've added an image at my question bro.

Answer (score 1):

```
requestApi(){
    const vm = this;
    const list = [
      { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "AAA" },
      { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "BBB" },
      { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "CCC" },
      { img: "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/dota2/images/mars/hero_mars93fd33s5.jpg", name: "DDD" }
    ];

    Promise.all(
        list.map(item=>new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            const img = new Image();
            img.addEventListener("load",function(){
                // here this means the img element
                this.__isOK__ = true;
                resolve(this);
            },{once:true})
            img.addEventListener("error",function(){
                this.__isOK__ = false;
                resolve(this);
            },{once:true});

            img.src = item.img;
        }))
     ).then(arr=>{
        const success = arr.filter(img=>img.__isOK__);
        console.log(`Finish. We had loaded ${arr.length} pictures. ${success.length} of them was successed`);

        vm.todos = list;
     })
}
```

Comment: you don't need that var `vm` - other than that, this is close to what I was about to post :p